# NSNotificationCenter addObserver in subclass

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, subclass, superclass, nsnotifications

I register for being notified in superclass (UIViewController) like so:

**SuperClass.m**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(notification:)
                                                 name:@"Notification"
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)notification:(NSNotification *)notification {

    // Do something for SuperClass with the notification
}
```

Now In subclass (subclass of SuperClass.m) I also listen for the same notification like so:

**SubClass.m**

```
- (void)notification:(NSNotification *)notification {

    // Do something specific for SubClass with the notification
}
```

Is this an acceptable (codewise) way to deal with having a general behaviour when acting on a notification in a superclass and to having a more specific behaviour when acting on a notification in a subclass?

Comment: Yes it is. Comments have to be too long.

Comment: Yes by using this when you call this notification function, it is called in Super Class and its sub class. You can consider this as acceptable code, if you want to load data in all view's for example, you need to refresh all your data when your application comes from background..

Comment: Ok great. At first when coding I thought ONLY the subclass' method would be called but for some reason it seems that both the superclass' observer and the subclass' observer are called. That's why I'm not calling super in my subclass' observer.

Comment: @PeterWarbo When I run my tests, it seems you must call super.  Your fears are correct.

Comment: @CodaFi must? If I call super then the superclass' observer will be called twice (by me from super in the subclass and the framework) That's why I'm not specifically not calling super...

Comment: I've got logs set up to trip in both the subclass and the superclass, and the superclass' one is not called without an explicit super call.

Comment: That is interesting. That's not the behavior I experienced. Can you share your sample project?

Comment: If both methods are being executed, you must have one instance of each class alive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when you want to allow more specific behavior in the subclass, while still maintaining the general behavior in the superclass, you have the subclass call `super`. For example, the `-[UIViewController viewDidAppear:]` documentation says:

> You can override this method to perform additional tasks associated with presenting the view. If you override this method, you must call `super` at some point in your implementation.

So your notification setup is fine (although it's a bit weird to have a `NSNotification` object as a parameter to a method you expect to be overridden) — but you'll want to call `[super notification:notification]` to get the superclass's behavior as well.

Comment: I've confirmed this aswell now and I need to call super for the notification to reach the superclass. This is expected behaviour. Why I initially asked this question is because this was not the behaviour I exeperienced. Like jrturton wrote it seems that I must have 2 instances of each class alive.